# Running compiled ASP.net MVC 4 project locally on any Windows 7 PC w/o IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-mvc-4

OK, so let's forget worrying about visible code.

I have a compiled MVC 4 app written with Web API, Backbone, & HTML 5 configured for CRUD storage locally in compact SQL included in the app. Data is received from the Internet via API and stored locally in Db. Local Db also through API sends data to some remote MVC Website Db.

**Question:**

What else must be done for the user, running Windows 7 on a local PC or tablet (w/ ample storage), other than providing a zip file download containing the complile app and sql db?

Would I need some prepackaged canned "Update to 4.5 Net, etc, etc to run MVC 4 locallly", or would I need to create some custom system update accompanyer, or need I do nothing as the App will work fine on a local PC running Windows 7 standard with no IIS?

Answer (score 1):

You can't run ASP.net without a web server of some sort. IIS is the answer (unless you want to fiddle with Mono on Linux).

Host the app on an accessible website and give the user a URL. That's why you used ASP.NET instead of creating a winforms application, right?

Comment: The key here was I wanted a local database to keep much of what the app needs. Being local would mean faster app.

Comment: Maybe something a little more standard like [Local Storage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)?

Comment: local storage has limitations for me.

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel - Programs and Features - Turn windos features On

Internet Information Services + .Net Framework 4.5

Thats u need.

Comment: I would need the client to do that and I was hoping not to rely on their OS skill sets and just have it all setup for them.

Answer (score 0):

You MIGHT be able to try WebMatrix 2 since it comes with IIS Express...